# php not adding data to database by using file.php?data=value

Tags: php, post

I have a form that I want to submit it without reloading the page with jquery. I am trying to make a form that will send the data to MySQL database with PHP.
This is the code in submit button onclick:

```
e.preventDefault();
var data = JSON.stringify($("form").serialize());
$.post("insert.php?" + data);
```

and this is the PHP file :

```
<?php
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$gender = $_POST['gender'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$phoneCode = $_POST['phoneCode'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
if (!empty($username) || !empty($password) || !empty($gender) || !empty($email) || !empty($phoneCode) || !empty($phone)) {
 $host = "localhost";
    $dbUsername = "use";
    $dbPassword = "user_pass";
    $dbname = "test";
    //create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($host, $dbUsername, $dbPassword, $dbname);
    if (mysqli_connect_error()) {
     die('Connect Error('. mysqli_connect_errno().')'. mysqli_connect_error());
    } else {
     $SELECT = "SELECT email From register Where email = ? Limit 1";
     $INSERT = "INSERT Into register (username, password, gender, email, phoneCode, phone) values(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
     //Prepare statement
     $stmt = $conn->prepare($SELECT);
     $stmt->bind_param("s", $email);
     $stmt->execute();
     $stmt->bind_result($email);
     $stmt->store_result();
     $rnum = $stmt->num_rows;
     if ($rnum==0) {
      $stmt->close();
      $stmt = $conn->prepare($INSERT);
      $stmt->bind_param("ssssii", $username, $password, $gender, $email, $phoneCode, $phone);
      $stmt->execute();
      echo "New record inserted sucessfully";
     } else {
      echo "Someone already register using this email";
     }
     $stmt->close();
     $conn->close();
    }
} else {
 echo "All field are required";
 die();
}
?>
```

But it's not adding data to the database. I tried also writing the URL then the data like this: `insert.php?data=value`.But it didn't work. I am new to server-side and PHP, so I appreciate any help

Comment: you are sending the data as request parameters in the url. Hence they are in $_GET. Not in $_POST. See https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/ for the correct syntax to send the data as POST request